# Event inside Event in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

I have some problems when i using addListener of Google Maps API.

At first, i load some markers and i attach one event listener in all of them, like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', function() {
   var points = new cRota().loadRotaFromVeiculo(this.id_veiculo,
            $("#txtDataInicial").val(),
            $("#txtDataFinal").val(),
            $("#txtHora1").val(),
            $("#txtHora2").val()
            );
    this.map.removeMarkers();
    this.map.removeRoutes();
    this.map.removePolylines();


    this.polyline = new Polyline();
    this.polyline.setMap(this.map);
    this.polyline.setPoints(points);

    if (this.polyline.init()) {
        //Adiciona a polyline no mapa
        this.map.addPolyline(this.polyline);
    }

//Cria o window info para mostrar as informações da rota
    this.info_window = new InfoWindow();
    this.info_window.setMap(this.map);
    this.info_window.init();

    //Adiciona um marker pra cada ponto da polyline
    var marker_rota = new MarkerRota();
    marker_rota.setDataLocalizacao(points[0].data_localizacao);
    marker_rota.setVelocidade(points[0].velocidade);
    marker_rota.setLatitude(points[0].latitude);
    marker_rota.setLongitude(points[0].longitude);
    marker_rota.setMap(this.map);
    marker_rota.setIcon("m5.png");
    marker_rota.init();
    marker_rota.addListener();

    //Adiciona no mapa
    this.map.addMarker(marker_rota);
};
```

When i click in some marker, i load data from webservice and create a polyline.
After create a polyline, i instance the class called `MarkerRota`. This class, extends another class called `Marker`.

So, when i click in one marker in my map, the event is fired, and do all this, create the polyline and other marker.

In this other marker i also have an addListener in to execute other things.

But, the problem is, when i click in some marker generated before, the other marker is loaded, the event of this other marker created by `MarkerRota`, never is fired.

Here is the code of my function of class `MarkerRota`

```
MarkerRota.prototype.addListener = function() {
    //Copia a classe para uma var
    var that = this;
    //Adiciona o evento do click do marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, "click", (function() { 
        window.alert("TEST");
    }));
};
```

The property `this.marker` is an object of google.maps.Marker type.

Another strange thing that happens is that when I click on my first marker, the other marker is generated again and the click event is fired.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

If you need more code or more explanation just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you are not defining a new marker. But I won't know unless you add more code. So When you make the call:

```
MarkerRota.prototype.addListener = function() {
    //Copia a classe para uma var
    var that = this;
    //Adiciona o evento do click do marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, "click", (function() { 
        window.alert("TEST");
    }));
};
```

this.marker will still be your first marker. (why clicking the marker will repopulate the map with the same marker). Try creating a new marker in the MarkerRota class? Unless you already are.

Comment: The MarkerRota extends the class Marker, and this class have the init() function. In the init() function i create an google.maps.Marker object

Comment: I would also check that the this.map.removeMarkers() isn't removing the markers you want to see. I don't see you adding the marker to an array, unless you are doing it in the init. If you are doing it in the init then you need to add the listener inside the init or add the listener before the init.